# How to set PIG_HEAPSIZE value in a shell script triggering a pig job

Tags: shell, environment-variables, apache-pig

Also what can be the maximum value set for this. Please let me know any preconditions that I need to consider while setting this flag.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I configured the the value "PIG_HEAPSIZE=6144" just before the pig script as in the below:

```
PIG_HEAPSIZE=6144 pig \
    -logfile ${pig_log_file} \
    -p ENV=${etl_env} \
    -p OUTPUT_PATH=${pad_output_dir}  \
    ${pig_script} >> $log_file 2>&1;
```

And it worked!